# Show that: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\arctan\left(\frac{6k^2+4k}{4k^4+12k^3+13k^2+6k+5}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, inverse, pi

I was observing this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.233.540&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and by some experimental chance I got this result, but I can not prove it.

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\arctan\left(\frac{6k^2+4k}{4k^4+12k^3+13k^2+6k+5}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}\tag1$$

I tried to factorise $4k^4+12k^3+13k^2+6k+5$ but it is not factorable.

I guess that $$\arctan\left(\frac{6k^2+4k}{4k^4+12k^3+13k^2+6k+5}\right)=\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)$$

Does anyone knows how to prove $(1)?$

Comment: Any polynomial of degree less than 5 can be factored.

Comment: @DavidPeterson You mean easily by hand? Because all of them can be factored with Viete's formula. Am I wrong?

Comment: You don't want to factorize the denominator. In fact, the denominator's form is $w(1+uv)$, and the numerator is $w(u-v)$. The hard part is finding suitable values of $u, v, w$ to fit the form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $ u = \frac{2}{ k^2 + 2k + 1}, v = \frac{2}{  4k^2 + 4k + 1}$. Then,

$$ \arctan (u) - \arctan (v) = \arctan ( \frac{ u - v} { 1 + uv} ) = \arctan ( \frac{6k^2 + 4k } { 4k^4 + 12k^3 + 13k^2 + 6k + 5 }). $$

---

Then use $\sum_{k=1} \arctan \frac{2}{k^2} = \frac{3 \pi } { 4} $ (2.14) and $ \sum_{k=0} \arctan \frac{2}{(2k+1)^2 } = \frac{ \pi}{2}$ (2.8) as given in the paper, to justify

$\sum_{k=0}  \arctan ( \frac{6k^2 + 4k } { 4k^4 + 12k^3 + 13k^2 + 6k + 5 }) $
$= \sum_{k=0} \arctan \frac{2}{(k+1)^2} - \arctan \frac{2}{(2k+1)^2} $
$ = \sum_{k=1} \arctan\frac{2}{k^2} - \sum_{k=0} \arctan \frac{2}{ (2k+1)^2 } $
$ = \frac{ 3 \pi }{4} - \frac{\pi}{2} $
$= \frac{ \pi}{4} .$

Note: The 2 identities given in the paper can again be proved via telescoping sums.
2.8 is done via 1 telescoping sum ($u=2k, v = 2k+2)$.
2.14 is done via 2 telescoping sums.